# Community Promotion Ads - 2018 example markdown is wrong?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, markdown, advertising

Looking at [Community Promotion Ads - 2018](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/944/community-promotion-ads-2018) it states:

> ```
> [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
>
> [1]: http://image-url
> [2]: http://clickthrough-url
> ```

This is actually incorrect. The format should be:

```
[![alt-text for accessibility - description of the image][1]][2]

[1]: http://image-url "Tagline to show on mouseover"
[2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the answers are parsed to create the ads. While the usual Markdown rules here would mean that the mouseover text should be put where you suggest it, the parsing applied for community ads does convert the alt text to title text. You can verify this on the page showing the selected community ads (for example, mouseover any ad on [this's years list for AU](https://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/17637)). That's also probably why it's required that nothing else be in the 
post.

Example:

> [image]